# Invalid column error in SQL Server using "Where" condition

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing a small program in C#, and I get the "invalid column name" error using the `reader`, although my column name exists. I looked for previous answers on StackOverflow, but didn't really understand the answers given.. Can someone explains me :

- Why it bugs ?
- How to solve this problem ?

Here is my code.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("IP/{Station=0}/{Timestp=0}")]
    public ActionResult IP(int station, string timestp)
    {
        timestp = timestp.Replace("_", ":");
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(LocalDb)\MSSqlLocalDB;Integrated security=SSPI;database=Serene7_Default_v1");
        List<string> listeIps = new List<string>();

        string listDb = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT IdSource FROM [Serene5_Default_v1].[tcpdump].[TCPDump] WHERE Station = '{0}' AND TimeStp = '{1}';",station,timestp);
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(listDb, myConn);
        string listDb2 = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT IdSource,IdDestination FROM [Serene5_Default_v1].[tcpdump].[TCPDump] WHERE Station = {0} AND TimeStp = '{1}';", station, timestp);
        SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(listDb2, myConn);
        myConn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Serene7_Default_v1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TCPDump';", myConn);
        //opens connection
        SqlDataReader reader5 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader5.Read())
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(reader5[3]);

            // read 'name' column
        }
        reader5.Close();
        SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            listeIps.Add(reader[0].ToString());
        }

        reader.Close();
        // some stuff
        return View(MVC.Views.Common.Dashboard.DashboardIndex, dashboard);
    }
```

The `reader5` returns :

```
IdTransmission
TimeStp
IdSource
IdDestination
PortSource
PortDestination
Protocol
ToTheRight
ToTheLeft
Station
```

and the error is :

> Invalid column name 'Station'

Comment: Your code contains a sql injection! Always use parameters when you transfer values to a SQL. Never build a SQL-String with variables!

Comment: Yes I'm currently modifying it ^^ !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select query runs on [Serene5_Default_v1] DB, but you list table columns from [Serene7_Default_v1] DB. The table's schema in this two different DB equal?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `()` around column list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (IdSource,IdDestination)
=>
SELECT DISTINCT IdSource,IdDestination
```

`DISTINCT` can accept `()` only for one column.

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/HZYYS77760)**

---

Second thing:

```
string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT (IdSource,IdDestination) FROM [Serene5_Default_v1].[tcpdump].[TCPDump] WHERE Station = {0} AND TimeStp = '{1}';", station, timestp);
```

using `string.Format` could lead to SQL Injection attack. I strongly suggest to use parametrized query instead.

More info: [Parameterized Queries](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters)

Comment: what do the parenthesis have to do with anything ?

Comment: @JasonKrs There is no such construct in TSQL like DISTINCT()

Comment: Should I remove "distinct" too ? It still doesn't work ^^ !

Comment: @lad2025 yes there is but in sql server you can only pass one field in the distinct(). If you want more than one field you will have to omit the ()

Comment: @GuidoG That is why I posted example with two columns.

Comment: @lad2025 I edited my post, and as it is, it still doesn't work ^^ !

Comment: @lad2025 I agree with @GuidoG ; `DISTINCT(column)` is a standard SQL construct...

Comment: @JasonKrs And DISTINCT(col1, col2) won't work in SQL Server. Sorry, you don't get the point.

Comment: @JasonKrs Yes but the OP had 2 columns in the () so that was still an error

Comment: @lad2025  Hmmm I thought I got your point. I'm afraid you don't get mine. I wrote `DISTINCT(column)` and not `DISTINCT(col1, col2, ....,coln)` for a reason. I'm glad though OP's found an appropriate answer...I'm sure your anwer helps him though. Good help mate

Comment: @JasonKrs Ok, we could both agree that `there is no such construct in TSQL like DISTINCT()` was too general and imprecise.